# Capturing the output of shell DEBUGGING process

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

first of all, I know there are many ways to capture the output of a shell... I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715847/python-read-streaming-input-from-subprocess-communicate/17698359#17698359) and works fine:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["ping", "localhost"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            if "bytes" in line:
                print(line, end='')
```

But I need to get debugging info from de cmd, and this doesn't work... 
I am trying to get the output from [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/geth) that throws some info like:

```
mypc@thispc:~$ geth --light
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Starting peer-to-peer node               
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Allocated cache and file handles         
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Initialised chain configuration          
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Added trusted CHT for mainnet 
INFO [07-02|21:56:08] Loaded most recent local header
```

This is debugging info so, I don't know why, but i cannot capture normally to work with it. I need something like:

```
with Popen(["geth", "--light"], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
        for line in p.stdout:
            if "Loaded" in line:
                print("NICE!!")
```

Is there any way to do It?

Comment: Often debug messages are in stderr. Try to capture stderr with `stderr=PIPE` and then `p.stderr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to **kwarunek** for the answer, It worked

> Often debug messages are in stderr. Try to capture stderr with
>   stderr=PIPE and then p.stderr

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(["geth", "--light"], stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True) as p:
    for line in p.stderr:
        if "Block synchronisation started" in line:
            print(line, end='')
```